# In Figma, how do you make it stop changing the zoom level when you click a comment?

Tags: figma

I'm working on a big project, that has a huge artboard.
There are a million comments. When I click a comment, then it zooms **all** the way out, so I can see the entire artboard (6% zoom). Which means that I lose track of where I were.

It appears to have something to do with the commenter having commented a lot on the given artboard. It might be because Figma tries to show me all the comments from the given author on the given artboard at the same time.

How do I make Figma stop adjusting the zoom, when I click a comment?

I have scavenged the entire menu structure and all the settings. I can't seem to find a setting that changes this.

### Solution attempt 1: ChatGPT suggested something that I either can't find or doesn't exist:

**First attempt:**

> 1. Click on your profile avatar in the top-right corner of the Figma app.
> 2. Select "Settings" from the dropdown menu.
> 3. In the Settings window, select the "Commenting" tab on the left side of the screen.
> 4. Under the "Zoom to fit comments" option, toggle the switch to the off position.

**Second attempt:**

> 1. Click on the "Hamburger" menu icon in the top-left corner of the Figma app.
> 2. Select "Preferences" from the menu.
> 3. In the Preferences window, select the "Commenting" tab.
> 4. Under the "Zoom to fit comments" option, toggle the switch to the off position.

Neither of these things exists.

### Solution attempt 2: Click <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> afterwards

I figured, that maybe I could simply click <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>, and then hopefully, it would get me back to were I were. But that wasn't the case.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can't reproduce the problem. Clicking on a comment does nothing except bring up the dialog to add another comment.

Comment: I can conclude that it has something to do with the commenter having commented A LOT on the given artboard. It might be becuase Figma tries to show me all the comments from the given author on the given artboard at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably what it is. I don't think there is is anyway to change that behaviour in figma.  The ChatGPT stuff is just absolute nonsense.